# vegas pro - how to set hexadecimal color values

Tags: colors, sony-vegas

vegas pro video editor has a strange color settings
it uses a format like this - `0.09, 0.86, 0.86, 1.0`
`1.0` is alpha but - how to know what values are for `#0099cc` (for example)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use, for example, the website
[RGB to HSV color conversion](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.html)
to convert the colors from RGB to HSV.

For your example of `#0099cc`, when entering the hex value and pressing Convert:

[image]

The HSV values are in percentage, so need to be divided by 100.
This then gives: `1.95;1.0;0.8`.
The R,G,B values are divided by 255 to change the range from
`0..255` to `0..1`.

I have heard it mentioned that if you change the color picker to RGB,
Vegas Pro will use RGB values. (I don't use it so cannot verify).

Comment: thanks a lot. Have you any idea why vegas keeps things so complicated, comparing to all-present hex values?

Comment: Some genius developer made this wonderful decision, and everyone is stuck with it ever since.